# Removed one kitchen cabinet others will be fine?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets

I will be remodeling my kitchen later this year.  Right now, there was a sale on the refrigerator I wanted so I ordered it.  I had to remove the cabinet above where the refrigerator will go due to the new height.

The cabinet directly next to the refrigerator cabinet was attached to it via two small nails.  All cabinets are screwed through the drywall into cinder block.

There is no way that those two little nails are the make or break for the load the adjacent cabinet is under, right?  The picture shows the nails.  My understanding of joining the cabinets, while I'm sure it may distribute some load, is to square things up.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, the only purpose of the two nails were to align the cabinet edges together.  The screws in the back panel is what holds the cabinet up and provide the load support.

Comment: Accepting.  I also received confirmation offline from an installer friend.  Cheers.